# Store objects of an abstract type

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an abstract class/interface:

```
class MyInterface {
    public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;
        virtual ~MyInterface(){}
};

class MyImplemented : public MyInterface {
    public:
        virtual void foo(){ /*do something*/ };
}
```

and I want to have a vector that can store `MyInterface` objects, which I intend to store objects of `MyImplemented` class.

Is there another way to do this other than making a vector of pointers to `MyInterface` objects? i.e.

```
 std::vector<MyInterface*> myVector;
```

Also, if `MyInterface` is a concrete class, would anything change?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to have a vector that can store `MyInterface` objects, but you don't want to make a `vector<MyInterface*>`?

Comment: There isn't a difference in the storage whether it's abstract or concrete

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyInterface>>` is an other way ;-)

Comment: @crush: Since those _aren't_ `MyInterface` objects (indeed, no such thing can even exist), it's a fair question.

Comment: @crush yes. I want to avoid dealing with pointers if that's possible

Comment: So you don't want a collection of pointers, but a collection of objects. Like [**this**](http://ideone.com/5LfxTv)? I don't think you can do that with an abstract class/interface. You should use the reference counted pointers instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's just an improvement, but basically it's the same: you could store [**`unique_ptr`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)s instead of raw pointers.

But conceptually, you'll have to use pointers, as it's the only way to deal with polymorphism in this case.

Then

> I want to have a vector that can store MyInterface objects, which I intend to store objects of MyImplemented class.

If you know you'll store only objects of type `MyImplemented`, you could also just use an `std::vector<MyImplemented>` directly.

Comment: Polymorphism doesn't require pointers. Not slicing requires pointers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know polymorphism can also be done with references, though I believe an `std::vector<MyInterface&>` would be quite inconvenient in this case. Were you implying something else with "Polymorphism doesn't require pointers"? (I may have missed something then).

Comment: (a) It would not only be inconvenient: it is not possible with that syntax. (b) No, just correcting the second paragraph in your answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I recognize it wasn't strictly and pedantically correct. My mistake :)

Comment: then is it possible to make a vector of references?

Comment: @Chin No, because of the requirements of `std::vector` about [_the type of elements it will hold_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). This type must be CopyAssignable, and CopyConstructible, and references don't meet these requirements. (In C++11, these changed to MoveAssignable, and MoveConstructible).

Answer (score 3):

You can use smart pointer instead of built-in pointer (std::unique_ptr) or you can use boost::any and then cast to real type

Comment: Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you should precise that `boost::any` would be less flexible than pointers, as you have to _know_ the underlying type before doing a `boost::any_cast`, thus removing the ability to use objects stored in the vector through the abstract interface.

Comment: JBL: You are right - boost::any is not the best choice for this case

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have only MyImplemented , then there is no reason why you can't do

std::vector myVector;

The memory allocation is WAY easier with that layout, and you may get some performance boosts as well, as the memory layout (can be) more cache friendly.

This (however) implies a one-to-one relationship between interface and implementation. In that case, there is very little need to use polymorphism: it makes your code more complicated. You also take a (small) performance hit with virtual function calls.

What would NOT work is this:

std::vector myVector;//SO BAD

Because of narrowing: you need to use references of some type.